# Cannot convert IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<T> for different mscorlib versions

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I'm messing with a few generic classes in which I have a collection class which contains a method to load objects from a DTO collection, fetching the child objects using a `Func`

```
    public void LoadCollection<C, D>(IEnumerable<D> dtos, Func<D, C> fetch)
        where D : class
    {
        foreach (var dto in dtos)
            this.Add(fetch(dto)); // Can't assign a C to a C??
    }
```

(the C is constrained on the class def)

Everything else is working fine - but I get the message that I can't convert a C to a C. If I remove the `this.Add` and debug, checking the type after it's fetched; it returns a C (`item is C` = true), trying to add that to the list however throws invalid arguments even though the constraint on the list is on that very C.

Attempting to use `this.AddRange` also doesn't work citing `IEnumerable<T> v4.0.0.0` cannot be assigned to `IEnumerable<T> v2.0.5.0` (note the diff versions of mscorlib)

Is there an easy way to find out what's referencing the older mscorlib? Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: 2.0.5.0 is the Silverlight/PCL version of mscorlib, IIRC. Please give us more context about what's calling this, project types, framework versions etc. Also, please give more context about the class in which this is declared. Is it a generic type? What does `Add` take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is one like this:

```
class MyCollection<C>
{
    private List<C> list = new List<C>();

    public void Add<C>(C item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Note that both `MyCollection` and `Add` declare a type parameter called `C`. This will result in a warning like this even without the call to `Add`:

```
Test.cs(8,21): warning CS0693: Type parameter 'C' has the same name as the type
        parameter from outer type 'MyCollection<C>'
Test.cs(4,20): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
```

The `Add` call will have errors like this:

```
Test.cs(10,9): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
        'System.Collections.Generic.List<C>.Add(C)' has some invalid arguments
Test.cs(10,18): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'C
        [c:\Users\Jon\Test\Test.cs(4)]' to 'C'
Test.cs(8,21): (Location of symbol related to previous error)
```

This has nothing to do with the mscorlib differences, which may or may not still be an issue.

Moral: heed compile-time warnings! They can give you clues to other errors. Warnings in C# are sufficiently rare that you should almost *always* have warning-free code.

Comment: Don't know whether to accept my own or yours Jon - it seems like as soon as I press the 'Ask Question' button on SO my brain kicks in :)

Comment: @Jodrell I do end up answering my own question a lot of the time as it's usually just brain lag (Monday etc).... If noone else comes up with the answer (not saying that's the case here but I did post the answer at about the same time as Jon's) then surely it's better to put the answer on SO than to leave it? This is a learning site after all...or are you talking about *accepting* your own answers?

Comment: @GrantThomas Ok yes but, theres somthing to it. If you ask a question and answer it at the same time as another contributor you should give them the credit as thanks for the effort. Assuming they are correct of course. (before I go further off topic ...

Comment: @Jodrell Yes I agree with this - my first comment was meant in jest

Answer (score 1):

Always answer my own question 5 seconds after posting :(

Realised I was constraining C again in the `LoadCollection` method

Changing to this fixed it:

```
   public void LoadCollection<D>(IEnumerable<D> dtos, Func<D, C> fetch)
        where D : class
    {
        foreach (var dto in dtos)
            this.Add(fetch(dto));
    }
```

Comment: Try Rubber Ducking then :P